# phplot setDataColors() function not taking values from array

Tags: php, charts

For drawing pie chart in php page ,I am using functions from phplot.php.
But I have to display particular color for particular field.So I gave data and corresponding colos in an array.

Here is my code:

```
$pieColors = array('Ready' => 'Green', 'Rebooting' => 'Maroon', 'Running' => 'Blue' );

$data = array(0=>array(status=>'Ready',count=>25),1=>array(status=>'Rebooting',count=>25),2=>array(status=>'Running',count=>65));
```

For passing matched colors to setdataColors(), I loop over the `$data` and `$pieColors`

```
$count=count($data);
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){
       foreach ( $pieColors as $k => $v ){
              if($data[$i]['status'] == $k){
                   $overrideColors = $v;
 }}}

//Drawing pie chart
$plot = new PHPlot_truecolor(500, 300);
$plot->SetImageBorderType('none');
$plot->SetDataType('text-data-single');
$plot->SetDataValues($data);
$plot->SetPlotType('pie');
$plot->SetTitle($pool);
 //setting colors
$plot->SetGridColor('white');
$plot->SetTextColor('white');
$plot->SetPieLabelColor('white');
$plot->SetShading(0);
$plot->SetLabelScalePosition(0.2);

#set legend
foreach ($data as $row)
      $plot->SetLegend($row['status']);

 $plot->SetLegendPixels(380, 5);

 $plot->SetDataColors($overrideColos);

# Make the background transparent against the page
 $plot->SetBackgroundColor('#555555');
 $plot->SetTransparentColor('#555555');
 $plot->SetPrintImage(False);
 $plot->DrawGraph();
 $chart = $plot->EncodeImage();
```

While printing It displays error like `Invalid color`.

What is wrong in my code.?

Any one please take a look and suggest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colors we are passing to setDataColors() should match exactly with the colors of RGB array in phplot.php.Case sensitive as well as the colors should be there.

In my case 'Green' is in RGB array is 'green'.Thats why it showed error like 'Invalid color'